# Simpler/Alternative way to understand Regularization

Tags: machine-learning

I am reading about regularization [from this link](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#svm) and I cannot understand how I should correlate this particular concept to penalization.

> There is one bug with the loss function we presented above. Suppose that we have a dataset and a set of parameters W that correctly classify every example (i.e. all scores are so that all the margins are met, and Li=0Li=0 for all i). The issue is that this set of W is not necessarily unique: there might be many similar W that correctly classify the examples. One easy way to see this is that if some parameters W correctly classify all examples (so loss is zero for each example), then any multiple of these parameters λW where λ>1 will also give zero loss because this transformation uniformly stretches all score magnitudes and hence also their absolute differences.

I'm guessing I can visualize this as multiplying the coefficients of a straight line equation in 2D and satisfying the equation despite the multiplied coefficients. Or is there a better way to think about it?

> For example, if the difference in scores between a correct class and a nearest incorrect class was 15, then multiplying all elements of W by 2 would make the new difference 30.
>
> In other words, we wish to encode some preference for a certain set of weights W over others to remove this ambiguity. >

I don't understand this statement. Am I correct in understanding that a unique set of weights/parameters is desirable (but why?)?

> We can do so by extending the loss function with a regularization penalty R(W). The most common regularization penalty is the L2 norm that discourages large weights through an elementwise quadratic penalty over all parameters:
>
> $R(W)$ = $\sum_k\sum_l W_{k,l}^2$

Why are large weights discouraged?

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is exactly correct: if we have a set of equivalent equations to solve the problem, we generally want the one with the smallest coefficients.

```
y = x1 + 3 * x2 - 2 * x3
```

is preferred to

```
y = 10 * x1 + 30 * x2 - 20 * x3
```

even when softmax or other natural scaling easily deals with the difference.

This has various advantages in practice.  Smaller numbers have less chance of overflow.  Solution searches don't run into extremely large or small values.  Non-linear relationships stay within reasonable bounds, preserving computational accuracy -- which is especially important when the training is making its initial search for a region of convergence.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Another important advantage of regularization (in addition to the great Prune's explanation) is that it reduces the overfitting of model/hypothesis. A model trained using regularized cost function migh have worse performance on a training set but will generalize better on the values outside of the training set.